# Error 1022: Can't write; duplicate key in table 'tablesample'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am relatively new to MySQL and while attempting to forward engineer the tables from my EER Diagram, I keep getting Error 1022.

Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1022: Can't write; duplicate key in table 'avaya'
SQL Code:

---

```
-- Table `mydb`.`avaya`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`avaya` (
  `avaya_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_no` INT NULL,
  `date` DATE NULL,
  `avaya_pw` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `requestor` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`avaya_id`),
  INDEX `id_no_idx` (`id_no` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `id_no`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_no`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`employee` (`id_no`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

SQL script execution finished: statements: 8 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch

I am currently stuck.

Comment: "duplicate key in table 'avaya' ." is the answer. That means the value that you want to add already exists and it seems a primary key, but PK are unique

Comment: Yes, I set the avaya_id as the PK for this table. What I'm not able to grasp is the idea of an 'existing value' - a duplicate one at that - if I'm still on the process of creating the table.

Comment: That means you tried to insert the same thing twice. Primary key acts as a unique identifier - there can be only one - just like Highlander. Check what you're inserting, and figure out why you have the same value inserted twice. In this case, we lack data you're sending to the database to tell you "there, that record is evil, kill it".

Comment: I understand the part about the primary key being unique, as I have stumbled upon a different 'duplicate key' error that involved inserting rows to a table and the fix was to delete/drop the entry from that table. In this case, however, I haven't inserted anything yet. I'm still forward engineering the database from the EER model I've created. Basically, I'm still creating the table, without records. I forgot to mention that the error popped out when I was on the last part of 'Commit Progress'. @N.B.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out what went wrong. As I have 11 tables, some of the foreign keys have identical names. I've renamed them from every table and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Script tries to create a table, which already exists. This can happen, if you ran it twice.

To delete the old table, prepend script with:

```
drop table if exists mydb.avaya;
```

However, you would have to do it for every table. Even worse, your changes would be lost when you generate script from EER again. Usually there is an option to auto generate those statements, but it depends on software, that you use.

To delete *whole* database and start again, run in mysql console:

```
drop database mydb.avaya;
create database mydb.avaya;
```

Comment: Already tried dropping the schema, table, and database. Still getting the error. I'm not sure if the problem is within my constraints.